# Is it possible to clone an AST in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have an AST that I have created by parsing source-code using the Clang library. I would like to clone the AST so that I can parse some other code which might be invalid. If it is invalid, I will return to my clone for parsing further source-code snippets. I don't want to have to parse the same source-code twice for performance reasons.

The Clang AST representation is very rich, and some nodes contain pointers to other nodes.

Does Clang provide a utility for easily cloning ASTs that handles this complexity?